# Trigger que borre despues de insertar

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo dos tablas, tabla de nuevos y tabla registrados lo que quiero es que lo que este en nuevos se pase a registrado cuando se haga un update a un boleano (Aceptado=1 lo mande a registrados) y despues de que se haya insertado la informacion de nuevo a registrados borre ese mismo de nuevos, intente hacer un trigger que hiciera eso pero aunque me lo guarda bien a la hora de hacer dicha operación el trigger no avanza y no hace las operaciones

```
        BEGIN
CREATE TRIGGER `disparar_al_registrar` AFTER UPDATE ON `nuevos` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO registrados (Num_Registrado, Nombre_Registrado, TipoRegistrado_Id_Registrado, Semestre_Registrado, Facultad_Registrado, Contraseña) SELECT Matricula_Nuevo, Nombre_Nuevo, Id_nuevo, Semestre_Nuevo, Fac_Nuevo, Contra_Nuevo FROM nuevos WHERE Aceptado=1;

DELETE FROM nuevos WHERE Aceptado=1 OR Aceptado=0;//Aquí tomando en cuenta que 0 es rechazado y se borra, y 1 es aceptado y se manda a registrados
END;
```

De igual manera intente hacer 2 triggers (Uno que hiciera la inserción de una tabla a otra y después otro trigger que después de la inserción borre dicho en la tabla primero) pero solo chocan uno con otro *error 1442 -cant update table nuevos in stored function/trigger because it is already in use by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `disparar_al_registrar` BEFORE UPDATE ON `nuevos`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO registrados (Num_Registrado, Nombre_Registrado, Tipo_Id_Registrado, Semestre_Registrado, Facultad_Registrado, Contraseña) VALUES (Matricula_Nuevo, Nombre_Nuevo, Id_nuevo, Semestre_Nuevo, Fac_Nuevo, Contra_Nuevo)


CREATE TRIGGER `elimina_al_disparar` AFTER UPDATE ON `nuevos`
 FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM nuevos where Aceptado=1 OR Aceptado=0 //Aquí tomando en cuenta que 0 es rechazado y se borra, y 1 es aceptado y se manda a registrados
```

Estructura de las tablas

```
CREATE TABLE `nuevos` (
  `Num_Registro` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre_Nuevo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Matricula_Nuevo` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Contra_Nuevo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Semestre_Nuevo` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Fac_Nuevo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Id_nuevo` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Aceptado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `nuevos` (`Num_Registro`, `Nombre_Nuevo`, `Matricula_Nuevo`, `Contra_Nuevo`, `Semestre_Nuevo`, `Fac_Nuevo`, `Id_nuevo`, `Aceptado`) VALUES
(10, 'jejeje', '165656', 'xdd', '7', 'nznzznn', 1, NULL);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `registrados` (
  `Num_Registrado` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre_Registrado` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TipoRegistrado_Id_Registrado` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `Semestre_Registrado` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Facultad_Registrado` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Contraseña` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `registrados` (`Num_Registrado`, `Nombre_Registrado`, `TipoRegistrado_Id_Registrado`, `Semestre_Registrado`, `Facultad_Registrado`, `Contraseña`) VALUES
('130467', 'Maria del Carmen Arias Gonzalez', '1', '8', 'Educacion', 'toradora'),
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de enviar informacion de la tabla nuevos a la tabla registrados cuando se cambia Aceptado de NULL a 1, y que la información se borre de la tabla nuevos después de haber insertado la informacion a registrados

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar replicar tu entorno y plantear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado que quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Listo, le he incorporado las estructuras

Comment: Ya he entendido tu problema, ¿qué te parece limpiar la tabla nuevos periódicamente con un evento que elimine todos los que tengan `Aceptado=1`? Así soslayas el problema de un disparador que tiene que eliminar el mismo registro que lo dispara.

Comment: Genial, no habia pensado en algo así, ¿podrías dejar un ejemplo de como va la sintaxis para crear un evento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo limpiar la tabla `nuevos` periódicamente con un evento que elimine todos los que tengan `Aceptado=1`. Así soslayas el problema de un disparador que tiene que eliminar el mismo registro que lo dispara:

```
CREATE EVENT watchdog ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND DO
  DELETE FROM nuevos WHERE Aceptado=1;
```

Recuerda activar:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Espero que resuelva tu problema

En el manual tienes todas las opciones:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html